# How to convert a string to a blob?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loopbackjs

I need to convert a string to a blob

```
 export function getBlob (assetUrl, callback) {
    const  myBlob = new Blob([assetUrl], { type: 'application/pdf'})  
    console.log("ASSETURL", typeof assetUrl )
    console.log("MYBLOB" + myBlob)
    console.log("MYBLOB"+ typeof myBlob)
    console.log("MYBLOB" + JSON.stringify(myBlob))
    callback(myBlob.result)
 }
```

what i get from the first `console.log` is a uri string, of 40.3KB, i try to convert it into a blob. 
What i get from the second `console.log` is MYBLOB[object Blob]
What i get from the third `console.log` is MYBLOB object 
and what i get from the fourth `console.log` is MYBLOB{} an empty object.
The file is saved in the state as "undefined", and it's not stored on the database.
More, if i'm using blob file, what kind of type should i use for model in loopback?

I can't understand what is wrong. Anyone can help?

Comment: Blobs don't have a `result` property.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts si it's callback(myBlob) ? And why it says myBlob is undefined?

Comment: It doesn't say `myBlob` is `undefined`. _you_ said `myBlob` prints `[object Blob]`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yeah, i said when i set the new state then assetBlob (where myBlob is stored) is settled as undefined. Btw i fixed (myBlob.result) to (myBlob), and it stores a blob file now in the database, but it's just { } this. why?

Comment: Because blobs don't have any enumerable properties. `JSON.stringify()` only serializes enumerable properties.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thank you, but i'm not really getting it. Ok with what you just said, but why when i store it in the database i store an empty object?

Comment: No one would be able to answer that. You haven't shown how you're storing it to the database.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts here's this part of the code https://codesandbox.io/embed/kind-albattani-kx0fx?fontsize=14 .  i store it in assegnUri

Comment: @PatrickRoberts sorry, here's the updated code https://codesandbox.io/embed/kind-albattani-kx0fx

Comment: `const fileReader = new Blob([assetUrl], { type: "application/pdf" });` doesn't make any sense. That's not a `FileReader`, that's a `Blob`, and blobs don't have an `onload` method...

Comment: Your `propTypes` also don't declare an `account.assetUrl`, so where is that even coming from...?

Comment: ok for the propTypes, i fixed it. But what do you suggest for the blob? how can i store and retrive it from the database?

Comment: I have no clue what `this.props.actions.account.setAssetBlob(assetBlob);` does. I _still_ have no idea where `this.props.account.assetUrl` comes from. There's just not enough information here to ask a proper question, and dumping code that makes no sense is not getting any closer to an answer.

Comment: I put a tag of reactjs because i'm using reactjs, this.props.actions.account.setAssetBlob(assetBlob); is an action that set the attribute AssetBlob of the state of the application with the value in (assetBlob). When i declare assetUrl i say that it's an attribute of account in the state, that's what this.props.account.assetUrl comes from.